# UIButton can't handle touch events while it's animating

Tags: ios, swift

I made a custom button that its animating by growing and then coming back to original state (scale change) continually. Something like this:

```
class PulseButton: UIButton {

    private func setup() {
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.6, target: self, selector: #selector(self.animateButton), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func grow() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8) {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2.5, y: 2.5)
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    func shrink() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8) {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    @objc func animateButton() {
        grow()
        shrink()
    }
}
```

My issue is that the button touch event is not working while in growing state, only when it gets back to normal state (scaleX = 1, 1).

Is there a way to make it touchable in both states ?

Comment: Use the [`allowUserInteraction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewanimationoptions/1622440-allowuserinteraction) option of [`animate(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622451-animate).

Comment: Never knew about this option. If you can provide this as an answer I will accept it.